# How to make function work only for one button? Bootstrap-5 scroll to modals bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

What I want to achieve is to create two buttons:
1: that opens modal window
2: opens same modal and scrolls to bottom

code:

```
$('#menu-item-6706').on('click', function (){
    $('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $("#exampleModal .modal-body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#exampleModal .modal-body').prop("scrollHeight")}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

**Here is full jsfiddle snippet:** https://jsfiddle.net/mkx2auhj/1/

Script is almost working:

If you trigger for the the first time “launch demo modal” it opens modal.
If you trigger “Contact” it opens modal and scrolls to bottom. So it’s correct.

**The problem is if you hit “launch demo modal” again it scrolls to bottom again, which is not desirable.** I want it to open standard modal like the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have a bunch of buttons that all trigger the same modal with slightly
> different contents? Use `event.relatedTarget` and HTML data-bs-*
> attributes to vary the contents of the modal depending on which button
> was clicked. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

Move the `'shown.bs.modal'` event listener outside the click event and use `event.relatedTarget` to detect when the "Contact" button toggles the modal and then animate the modal accordingly. Try this

```
$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
    if( $(event.relatedTarget).is('#menu-item-6706') ){
        $("#exampleModal .modal-body").animate({ 
            scrollTop: $('#exampleModal .modal-body').prop("scrollHeight")
        }, 'slow');
    }
});
```